# Filter text while (after) parsing with XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I have some xml like:

```
<tag attr1="20190325235500 +0200">

</tag>
<tag attr1="20190326000000 +0200">

</tag>
<tag attr1="20190326000000 +0200">

</tag>
<tag attr1="20190326000000 +0200">
</tag>
```

I parse it with XMLPullParser like:

```
                if (parser.getName().equals(tag)) {
                    attr1 = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    item = new SomeItem(attr1);
                    item.setAttr1Name(attr1);
                    items.add(item);

                }
```

So I have a lot of records like `attr1="20190326000000 +0200"`

Now I want to filter all this records and leave only those which are starting `20190326`, for example.

I thought this would help me:

```
if (parser.getName().equals(tag) && parser.getAttributeValue(0).substring(0, 8).equals("20190326"))
```

but I was wrong and this `if` causing nullpointer exception in my `item.setAttr1Name(attr1);`

**What I can try to do? How to build right `if`?**

Maybe I should use something of Date, Calendar, DateFormat?..

Comment: use `parser.getAttributeValue(0) != null && parser.getAttributeValue(0).startsWith("20190326")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (parser.getName().equals(tag)) {
    attr1 = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
    if (attr1 != null && attr1.startsWith("20190326") {
        item = new SomeItem(attr1);
        item.setAttr1Name(attr1);
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```